# Julia: @fastmath not defined

Tags: julia

```
function init!(u)
n = length(u)
dx = 1.0 / (n-1)
@fastmath @inbounds @simd for i in 1:n
    u[i] = sin(2pi*dx*i)
end 
end
```

when I execute above function in IJulia, it prompts below texts:
@fastmath not defined

Comment: What version are you running? `@fastmath` was only introduced in v0.4

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My julia is v0.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Simon Byrne. My julia version is v0.3.8 less than v0.4. That's why julia prompts "@fastmath not defined".

Comment: No worries. By the way, you're unlikely to see much benefit in that code. You might also want to use `sinpi`.

Comment: Yes, `sinpi` is better.

Comment: should fastmath be added to Compat?

Comment: @AndyHayden It could be made a no-op, similar to [`@inline`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl/blob/63739de45e9099b2cc26b66d7567f914db789540/src/Compat.jl#L175-L177): would you mind filing an issue?